# Variable prompt based off another variable prompt - Dynamically update

Tags: obiee

I have two variable prompts containing dates (2013 / 01, 2013 / 02, etc...)

```
Prompt_Range1
Prompt_Range2
```

Prompt_Range1 goes back for historical data (1990's), up to the current date. Default is the current date (2014 / 07).

Prompt_Range2 goes from Prompt_Range1 up to the current date. Default is again the current date.

This is working on the initial page load, but I want to be able to change Prompt_Range1 to some past date and have Prompt_Range2 automatically update to include all dates between Prompt_Range1 and the current date after the page has loaded.

That is to say if I select 2012 / 05 for Prompt_Range1, then Prompt_Range2 will update to include the date ranges from 2012 / 05 to 2014 / 07. If I change Prompt_Range1 again, the dates in Prompt_Range2 should update accordingly. I don't want to click any buttons or otherwise complicate the issue for end users.

Is it possible to have dynamic prompt values like this?

Thanks.

*Edit - This is the SQL I am using to populate the end date.

```
SELECT "Date"."Month" 
FROM "MySubjectArea"
WHERE "Date"."Month"  BETWEEN '@{Prompt_Range1}' AND VALUEOF(CURRENT_MONTH)
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

**Edit - Did not find a solution, went back to using prefilled dates. Not ideal but working and simple.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You'll need to use an SQL expression in the available values to return dates based on the first variable.

EDIT:

Ah yes - have you tried ticking the box that says the prompt should be based on the value of all prompts?

Comment: I've updated the question with the SQL I am using. The problem remains, which is can I have this value update the moment I change the start date?

Comment: I don't the box you mention. Also, this is a variable prompt (if it makes a difference). Can you elaborate on your answer? Thanks

Comment: This is a variable prompt, not a column prompt. So the option 'based on the value of X' does not exist.

Comment: Why can't you use a column prompt?

Comment: I don't think I can use two column prompts on the same column. Would I like to get this working - Yes. But at this point I've moved on to other tasks. I appreciate your effort.